# Powershell to find all files in a folder NOT password-protected ZIP and delete them

Tags: powershell, security

I found this one - > https://superuser.com/questions/1150631/powershell-script-to-test-zip-passwords-from-file - > but it looks like what I need is a little different.

Is it possible to find all files in a folder which are NOT protected by a password and delete them?

Trying to solve the problem of people putting all kinds of sensitive files where these files shouldn't be.

Comment: Can you include your code as part of the question, and note any changes you've made if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.zip |
  Where-Object { '' | 7z t $_.FullName *>$null; $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 } |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- The above uses `7z`'s `t` command to verify archive integrity.
- Password-protected archives trigger a password prompt, which the pipeline input - the empty string (`'' | ...`) - provides a response to, causing the integrity verification to *fail* due to an invalid password, which `7z` reports via a *nonzero* exit code, reflected in PowerShell's
- `$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0` therefore returns `$true` only for archives that pass the integrity test, which are archives *without* password protection (`7z` then ignores the unneeded pipeline input).